# How did Palpatine learn Yoda was on Moraband?

Tags: star-wars, sith, yoda

At the end of Clone Wars TV show, Yoda is sent to Moraband by [Force Priestesses](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_Priestesses), as part of his trials for learning Force ghost ability. There he encounters ghosts of ancient Sith, and they tell him:

> There is no life after death. Only nothingness awaits you, Jedi. Your fear feeds our hunger for power. They will know you are here. We will tell them. You will die and be nothing.

Official explanation is that these ghosts are not real, because Sith truly cannot live after death. Instead, they are just illusions, presumably created by Priestesses to test Yoda.

But later we learn that Palpatine is really alerted to Yoda's presence on Moraband. He and Dooku then try to "break" Yoda and fail. Yet, the question remains: how did Palpatine learn that Yoda is on Moraband if Sith ghosts were not real? I doubt Force Priestesses would cooperate with him (maybe I'm wrong :)  )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Through Dooku’s connection to him

It is because Dooku had a strong connection to Yoda (having served as his apprentice for many years) that he could sense the presence of Yoda:

> PALPATINE: **Only the presence of someone significant to you would allow you to
> sense this ripple through time and space.**
>
> DOOKU: My old master, Yoda.
>
> PALPATINE: Yes. Master Yoda has come to Moraband, although *why*, I do not know.
>
> <sub>*The Clone Wars*, “Sacrifice”</sub>

The implication is that it was *Dooku* who sensed Yoda’s presence on Moraband. That said, a previous scene seems to indicate that Palpatine told Dooku to return to Coruscant *before* Dooku was able to communicate with him, though the scene still heavily implies that Dooku has sensed Yoda’s presence (as explicitly confirmed later).

Perhaps Palpatine sensed Yoda’s presence separately, whether through his strength in the Force or the presence of the dark side on Moraband, or both, or **perhaps he merely noted the perturbation in his apprentice through the Force** (if Dooku is connected to Yoda, Palpatine is doubtless connected to Dooku). This latter possibility is borne out through the assertion that “only the presence of someone significant to Dooku” could allow him to sense Yoda’s arrival. If this is the case, for Palpatine to have sensed it directly seems improbable.

Of course, Dooku could not have sensed Yoda’s arrival just *anywhere*, even with that connection. Only a planet so strong in the dark side of the Force would have triggered his senses.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that it might be this very connection that allowed  Palpatine to Force choke Dooku so easily from Coruscant: the bond between Master and Apprentice, from much time in proximity both physically and through the Force. Undoubtedly, though, both the presence of the dark side and the aid of Palpatine assisted Dooku in making contact. Had he tried to attack Yoda mentally by himself, he would most likely have failed, if he was even strong enough to make contact.

Comment: Somehow I doubt. It was Palpatine that informed Dooku that Yoda was on Moraband, not other way around. Your quote confirms that Dooku didn't have a clue until Palpatine told him .

Comment: My quote confirms explicitly that Dooku sensed the “ripple,” i.e. Yoda’s presence on Moraband.

Comment: Watch whole episode if you can. Palpatine summons Dooku on Coruscant. Only then he explains why did he called him, and why is was necessary to risk such trip (remember , Dooku is leader of CIS )

Comment: @rs.29 - It is *explicit* from the quote that Dooku sensed Yoda’s presence. Whether Palpatine did too is a bit unclear, but there is a *only* there, which strongly implies it. The phrasing from the earlier scene involves Dooku saying that he is “on his way.” He also seems to sense something before the droid enters. Most likely Dooku sensed something through his connection to Yoda, and Palpatine sensed Dooku’s thoughts through his connection. Alternately, he had just be communing with Sidious telepathically.

Comment: I can see that dooku sensed yoda while palpatine did not. And very easily at that. the very SAME happened in return of the jedi when vader sensed luke while palpatine could not.